# Groovy dataset findAll AST not available for closure

Tags: groovy, dataset

I have following code connecting to mysql. dataset findAll method giving the error message.

**code:**

```
def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
people.add( firstname:"James", lastname:"Strachan", id:1, location_id:10, location_name:'London' )
people.add( firstname:"Bob", lastname:"Mcwhirter", id:2, location_id:20, location_name:'Atlanta' )
people.add( firstname:"Sam", lastname:"Pullara", id:3, location_id:30, location_name:'California' )

def janFrequentBuyers = people.findAll { it.location_id > 10 && it.lastname == "Pullara" }.sql
println janFrequentBuyers
```

**error message:**

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: testdb_closure7. Is the source code on the classpath?
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Here is sample code I am using MySQL:

```
static main(args) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driverClassName)
    try {
        sql.execute("drop table PERSON")
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    // create table
    sql.execute('''create table PERSON (
                    id integer not null primary key,
                    firstname varchar(20),
                    lastname varchar(20),
                    location_id integer,
                    location_name varchar(30)
               )''')
    // now let's populate the table
    def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
    people.add(firstname: "James", lastname: "Strachan", id: 1, location_id: 10, location_name: 'London')
    people.add(firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Mcwhirter", id: 2, location_id: 20, location_name: 'Atlanta')
    people.add(firstname: "Sam", lastname: "Pullara", id: 3, location_id: 30, location_name: 'California')
    //get first now
    def results = sql.firstRow("select firstname, lastname from PERSON where id=1").firstname
    println results

    //query using where class
    def janFrequentBuyers = people.findAll { it.location_id > 10 && it.lastname == "Pullara" }
    println janFrequentBuyers.each { println it }

}
```

Error Message:

```
 groovy -cp ./mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar j.gy
James
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: testdb$_main_closure1. Is the source code on the classpath?
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: testdb$_main_closure1. Is the source code on the classpath?
        at testdb.main(j.gy:36)
```

I changed it h2 DB, still getting the same error:

```
 groovy db.gy
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: db$_run_closure1. Is the source code on the classpath?
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: db$_run_closure1. Is the source code on the classpath?
        at db.run(db.gy:19)
```

code:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.168')
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:h2:mem:db1", "sa", "sa", "org.h2.Driver")
sql.execute('''create table PERSON (
                id integer not null primary key,
                firstname varchar(20),
                lastname varchar(20),
                location_id integer,
                location_name varchar(30)
           )''')
// now let's populate the table
def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
people.add(firstname: "James", lastname: "Strachan", id: 1, location_id: 10, location_name: 'London')
people.add(firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Mcwhirter", id: 2, location_id: 20, location_name: 'Atlanta')
people.add(firstname: "Sam", lastname: "Pullara", id: 3, location_id: 30, location_name: 'California')
//query using where class
def janFrequentBuyers = people.findAll { it.location_id > 10 && it.lastname == "Pullara"}
janFrequentBuyers.each{println it}
println "Sort on First Name"
people.sort{it.firstName}.each{println it}
```

forgot check with you what version of groovy your using?

```
 groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.1.2 JVM: 1.6.0_24 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Comment: Have a look at my update.

Comment: Have a look at my update again.

Comment: Were you able to track down the issue ?

Comment: No, I have added class loader debug, i can see it loads database driver. its failing on the closer. not sure how to debug this one.

Comment: Glad to know I wasn't worth of the bounty. I will try harder to replicate the issue and fix it. ;)

Comment: I tried different version of groovy version, I am getting the error, not sure why:)

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy source for [DataSet](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/DataSet.html) should be on the classpath. Refer the excerpt after the example in the API.

Follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585808/groovy-script-classpath) on how to add the source to classpath.

**Sample:-**

```
//Add ojdbc14.jar to groovy classpath for the script
>groovy -cp C:\Oracle\11gR2\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14 DataSetTest.groovy

//DataSetTest.groovy
import groovy.sql.Sql
def db = [url:'jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoradb:1521:myoradb', user:'johndoe',
          password:'anything', driver:'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

def airport = sql.dataSet("AIRPORT")
def cmh = airport.findAll{it.airportid == "KCMH"}

println cmh.sql

//Prints
select * from AIRPORT where airportid = ?
```

**UPDATE** [Groovy 2.1.4]

**First Approach**
I tested the same sample as you have used by putting the source in the classpath and it works like a charm for me. Following steps:

- I installed MySql Server 5.6.12 from scratch.
- Downloaded `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14` manually without using `@Grab`
- Added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` in the classpath.
- Copied your script (note I do not have `static main(args)`) & then ran the script.

**Detials**

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflowdb'
def dbUser = 'root'
def dbPassword = ''
def driverClass = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, driverClass)

try {
    sql.execute("drop table PERSON")
} catch (Exception e) {}
// create table
sql.execute('''create table PERSON (
                id integer not null primary key,
                firstname varchar(20),
                lastname varchar(20),
                location_id integer,
                location_name varchar(30)
           )''')
// now let's populate the table
def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
people.add(firstname: "James", lastname: "Strachan", id: 1, location_id: 10, location_name: 'London')
people.add(firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Mcwhirter", id: 2, location_id: 20, location_name: 'Atlanta')
people.add(firstname: "Sam", lastname: "Pullara", id: 3, location_id: 30, location_name: 'California')

//get first now
def results = sql.firstRow("select firstname, lastname from PERSON where id=1").firstname
println "First Row First Name: $results"

//query using where class
def janFrequentBuyers = people.findAll { it.location_id > 10 && it.lastname == "Pullara"}
janFrequentBuyers.each{println it}

println "Sort on First Name"
people.sort{it.firstName}.each{println it}
```

Command Prompt:

```
//Command:-
groovy -cp C:\tools\MySql\connector\mysql-connector-java-5.1.14\mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar DataSetTest.groovy
```

Results:

```
First Row First Name: James
[id:3, firstname:Sam, lastname:Pullara, location_id:30, location_name:California]
Sort on First Name
[id:2, firstname:Bob, lastname:Mcwhirter, location_id:20, location_name:Atlanta]
[id:1, firstname:James, lastname:Strachan, location_id:10, location_name:London]
[id:3, firstname:Sam, lastname:Pullara, location_id:30, location_name:California]
```

[image: Console Output]

**Second Approach**
I tested the same in Groovy Console by adding the jar to classpath from the console directly. Got the same result.

**Third Approach**
I tested the script in Groovy Console using `@Grab` as shown below. Got the same result.

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.14')
```

Try to follow any of the approach.

*Note:-*
I did not use `static main()` because it is not needed for a groovy script, although I tested successfully with it as well.

If you still face any problem, then try to load the jar using root loader as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605652/2051952).

Comment: thanks, but my error message is different. I can able to connect and select the data. problem is when I use findAll with filter

Comment: @sfgroups As I mentioned earlier, the concerned jar has to be in groovy classpath, see my update to the answer which I tested successfully for oracle. You should use MySql equivalent of the same.

Comment: @sfgroups I am not sure about MySql but do you need `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` for the source or `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.jar`? I will try testing your sample. In the meantime, can you put the jar in `lib` directory of GROOVY_HOME and try testing?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.jar is mysql jdbc driver, it also in lib directory. as you see from the output, it creates table and gets the data. it fails on findAll function. thanks for the help.

Comment: it works in groovyconsole. I am behind the proxy, not able test this using Grab. are you able to run this code with Spring Tool Suite IDE? I created the test groovy class in grails project, trying to run as script.

Comment: @sfgroups I did not use STS. Were you able to find out what the problem was? Try to run the script in `grails console` as well although it is not much of a difference running in groovy console.

Comment: @dmahaptro I was not able to fix the classloader issue. right now I am using Grails controller to connect to database. I will trying grooy dataset, when I find some time. thanks for your help

Comment: what version of groovy your using? look my h2db example

Comment: @sfgroups Tested in Groovy 2.1.4 and 2.1.3.