# How to use groovy Script everywhere?

Tags: java, groovy, command-line

My simple Groovy project contains two classes.
I added the containing path to the PATH variable.

***ExampleClass.groovy***

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class ExampleClass {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        UtilClass util = new UtilClass()
        util.testPrint("Success!")
    }

}
```

***UtilClass.groovy***

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class UtilClass {

    void testPrint(String text) {
        println(text)
    }

}
```

When i run "ExampleClass.groovy" in the containing directory, everything is doing fine.
.But when i run "ExampleClass.groovy" elsewhere, i get this:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:
>   C:\Users\buehlmannt\IdeaProjects\MessageKeyRefactoring\src\ExampleClass.groovy:
>   6: unable to resolve class UtilClass  @ line 6, column 19.
>              UtilClass util = new UtilClass()
>                        ^
>
> C:\Users\buehlmannt\IdeaProjects\MessageKeyRefactoring\src\ExampleClass.groovy:
>   6: unable to resolve class UtilClass  @ line 6, column 26.
>              UtilClass util = new UtilClass()
>                               ^
>
> 2 errors

I allready tried to add the UtilClass to the classpath. But i was not able to call "this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL( new URL("./") )", because rootLoader returns a ClassLoader Object which does not have an addUrl Method.
--> [Watch second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585808/groovy-script-classpath)

What is the best way of doing this right?

Comment: Did you have classpath right?

Comment: I wasn't able to do this --> see supplement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes need to be in the classpath. There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

### Use a single .groovy file

Unlike Java, you can place multiple Groovy classes into a single file:

**ExampleClass.groovy**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class ExampleClass {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        UtilClass util = new UtilClass()
        util.testPrint("Success!")
    }

}

class UtilClass {

    void testPrint(String text) {
        println(text)
    }

}
```

And that's it. I will just work. *Note: The order in which the classes are listed in the file does not matter.*

### Add the classpath

This one a slightly more complex, and rather fragile because you have to consider where the classes are located on the filesystem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy -cp $WHEREEVER_THE_CLASSES_ARE_LOCATED

class ExampleClass {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        UtilClass util = new UtilClass()
        util.testPrint("Success!")
    }

}
```

### Package into a .jar

A more complex approach is to compile the classes with groovyc and package the compiled .class files into a .jar file. (I know I've done this, but unfortunately cannot find the code). In the end, you'd be able to execute the app like this: `java -jar example.jar`

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation!